# I am trying to write an advanced expression which executes when a value in the field equals to Day of that month

Tags: formula, expressions, servicemax

I have this field named **Billing Date** it is a number field where you enter just only the day number and I want it to run every month on that date.

So something like:

`IF(!(ISBLANK(BILLINGDATE)), BILLINGDATE = Day(TODAY), FALSE`

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use formulas to schedule recurring activities, nor can you assign to other fields using a formula. You may need to use Time-Dependent Workflow, Process Builder, or Scheduled Apex to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apex for this, you could write a [scheduled class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) that runs everyday to do what you want with the records that have a formula field with that expression returning `true`.

If you don't want or can't use Apex, you could similarly create a process builder to run on specific records (time-based actions) and use that a similar formula to set up the date in which you want to run the action (see the `DATE` [function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5)).

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble. I actually had to use this through servicemax engine process generator. So, I created a formula field with the given requirements and made it true in servicemax with the help of the following formula.

Comment: IF(Billing_Date__c == DAY( TODAY()),true,false).

Comment: Well my comment still applies. But if you want to do this within ServiceMax then you better contact their support for this.